# Disable LinkButton in UpdatePanel after first click

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, linkbutton

I am working on an ASP.NET webforms page that has the following asp markup (with additional controls stripped out):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPreviousTop" OnClick="LinkButtonPrevious_Click"
            Text="Previous" runat="server">
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Right now, if you click this LinkButton multiple times, the `LinkButtonPrevious_Click` event handler on the server side will fire as many times as the link was clicked. How can I make it so that the `lnkbtnPreviousTop` LinkButton is disabled after the first click, but the event handler still fires once and the UpdatePanel is refreshed?

I have tried adding `this.disabled = true;` to the OnClick attribute, but then the event handler code never gets hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the postback directly in the onclick, something like:

```
lnkbtnPreviousTop.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lnkbtnPreviousTop, "").ToString());
```

Comment: or, instead of setting the button to disabled,  you could change the buttons style to make it hidden.

Comment: I did try adding the onclick attribute as you suggested; however it caused the event handler to fire twice for each click. I abandoned this approach and essentially followed your second advice of manipulating the styles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm, couldn't figure this out in an update panel.

Answer (score 0):

can you share answer for solution disabled asp:LinkButton after first click?

@Michael Hornfeck

I try with functions javascript but i havn't answers

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function disabledLinkBringDataFlow() {
           
            document.getElementById('btnBringDataFlow').setAttribute("disabled", "");
           
            //document.getElementById("btnBringDataFlow").disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
```